# How can i send values from Javascript to ActionResult?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have this JS code that calls an ActionResult:

```
function SaveGif(url) {
$.get("/Home/SaveGif", function (data) {
    $("p").html(data);
});
```

}

how can i pass the URL parameter to my ActionResult?

this is my ActionResult:

```
        public ActionResult SaveGif(string URL)
    {

        var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        return Content("Saved");
    }
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this, pass it like query string

```
function SaveGif(url) {
$.get("/Home/SaveGif?URL="+url, function (data) {
    $("p").html(data);
});

``
```